# How to change an <a> tag into a button that plays sound without it moving around on my webpage using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, audio

I found some code that was helpful to initially solving an issue I had. The code is shown here.

**JS**:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
  <span id="dummy"></span>
    <a href="#" onclick="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Click here to hear a sound</a>
```

However when I try and play this code, unless I have hidden set to false I cannot hear any sound. Yet when I have it set to false, the sound plays and moves my button around for some bizarre reason. The button is an image rather than text. I was wondering if there was any way around this. I had considered using the button tag for it but its adds a frame around my picture which is something i don't want in my final result.

The sound file being played is only a short one (less than 5 seconds). I have discovered that i can only click the button to get the sound to play once. Is there a method of being able to have the sound playing on click more than once without having to refresh the page?

I have sorted out the sound problem, but I would like to be able to repeat the sound onclick whilst retaining the  tag structure. The link links to a dummy location at the same place on my webpage, but if I use button it throws my webpage out of sync, hence I am deferring to  tag, unless there is a way to remove all the edging from buttons of course.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTML 5 markup as follows:

```
<script>
function playSound(soundfile) {
    var audio=document.getElementById("dummy");
    audio.src=soundfile;
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

HTML 5:

```
<audio id="dummy"></audio>
<button type="button" onclick="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Click here to hear a sound</button>
```

Any questions? just ask :)